# Cannot find very simple Egg Scrambler

Tags: equipment, scrambled-eggs, hand-blender

I used to have a very simple egg scrambler, metal,  a kind of flexible wire spiral with a handle. As you beat with it, the flexible spiral would somewhat amplify your hand motion. Cannot find another one anywhere.

Comment: Are you asking for alternatives? Sources? Brand names? Frankly, I'd recommend a fork: it's the most ubiquitous egg-scrambler I know.

Comment: I second the use of forks.  Are you talking about a spiral whisk, though? Over-mixing eggs to scramble is actually detrimental to the eggs, I've found. It's best to just mix until it's a even color and not to introduce a lot of air. But I think it's a personal preference thing.

Comment: Does it look like one of these: http://www.craftsy.com/blog/2013/10/different-types-of-whisks/

Comment: @Catija the amount of air that should be beaten into eggs depends on the recipe you are using them for. Some recipes benefit of getting them foamy, in other they should be just liquefied with no air inside.

Comment: Fork for the win, you don't need fancy tools to scramble eggs

Comment: Personally I'd recommend a spoonula http://www.amazon.co.uk/ProCook-Silicone-Spoonula-Black/dp/B0026ONAEG it helps scrape all the egg from the sides and bottom of the pan. Also as they are soft silicone they don't scrape the pan. Especially important if using a non stick pan.

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably mean a [Spring Whisk](https://www.google.com/search?q=whisk&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=uYDJVIoUl63IBK-KgbgB&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=840&bih=500#tbm=isch&q=spring%20whisk) The ones with a flat spiral bottom can be had at Amazon. I'm not seeing any of the old style, with an open bottom. That shouldn't make much difference to an egg.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying to find.  If it is, there's one on ebay for $24.00 (link follows picture below)

[image]

http://www.ebay.com/itm/Vintage-Cutco-Pat-2390544-12-egg-beater-scrambler-Whisk-brown-Swirl-USA-/151228405377?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2335ea5681